# Multiple titles and images for the same Object on Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im working in a new web app, i created an action and an object in my facebook developers page.
All the users do the same, they "drop" an "object". The thing is, the name of the object is variable, so the same happens whit the link that i want to send them when they click in the facebook post.

There is a way to do this, or when every user drop an "object", to publish, i have to create a new facebook custom object in my app?